# How can I mock mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, nestjs

I am writing unit test. I need to mock ObjectId. How can I do this?

```
const mockTokenDto: CreateUserTokenDto = {
  token: 
    'a172c98424ad6c6269d398de476940e29feacea5f8ab270ecbc45262ec1d6f04a4abd223925bb0759e915f96c7aaf196',
  userId: '5fa1c587ae2ac23e9c46510f',
  expireAt: '2020-11-04T21:06:26.236Z',
}


export class CreateUserTokenDto {
  @IsString()
  token: string;
  @IsString()
  userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  @IsDateString()
  expireAt: string;
}
```

Comment: You can just create it with exsiting model `const mockUser  = new <UserModel>({data})` and save it later with mockUser.save()

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: [Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents) it is explained in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mock ObjectId using mongoose.Types.ObjectId

```
 const mockObjectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

 const mockTokenDto: CreateUserTokenDto = {
  token: 
    'a172c98424ad6c6269d398de476940e29feacea5f8ab270ecbc45262ec1d6f04a4abd223925bb0759e915f96c7aaf196',
  userId: mockObjectId,
  expireAt: '2020-11-04T21:06:26.236Z',
}
```

You can learn more about it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#types-objectid-js

Comment: That is not a mock.. that is a real ObjectId. this is useless for unit testing as it will be different everytime the function is called. Not sure why this is the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Found another way to mock ObjectId generation. Just mock ObjectID.generate. For example, mock with constant:

```
const { BSON } = require('bson');
jest.spyOn(BSON.ObjectID.prototype, 'generate').mockImplementation(() => {
    return Buffer.from('62a23958e5a9e9b88f853a67', 'hex');
});
```

Mock implementation can be replaced with chained 'mockImplementationOnce', if more than one id need to be generated

Answer (score 1):

### Jest mock for ObjectID

The accepted answer is not a mock.. it is a real `ObjectId`

If you came here looking to solve the problem of ever changing ObjectIds in your snapshots / tests then look no furhter.

Unfortunately mocking `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is not easy, if you try to `spyOn` or `jest.fn()` the exported type from `mongoose` you will get errors relating to primitive types.

Here is the solution:

### Create a wrapper around `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

This makes it easy to re-use the type across your codebase anyway,

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export type ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
export const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

### Spy on this wrapper in your setup file

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array

```
import * as ObjectIdWrapper from '../../src/shared/classes/object-id';


const mockId = new ObjectIdWrapper.ObjectId('62a23958e5a9e9b88f853a67');
const ObjectIdSpy = jest.spyOn(ObjectIdWrapper, 'ObjectId');

ObjectIdSpy.mockImplementation(() => mockId);
```